# Social networking analytics tools

Tags: facebook, social-networking, analytics

I'm looking for analytics tool for a Facebook application. I need to do a brief about free available tools.

Currently I'm only familiar with [Kontagent](http://www.kontagent.com/solutions/social-analytics/) web service (Its not free).

It works like this:
When a user performs an action that creates an important event, our application sends a log message to kontagent web service telling that an important event has taken place. Kontagent will then process and log this data, to returns reports, graphs, and metrics.

I've made some searching about it and found only payed tools (RavenTools, Rankur, Radian 6)

Do you know of any free tools that provide analytics capabilities for Facebook Events?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your brief is already done, but for anyone else looking at this, if you have a Facebook page (such as a fan page or a business page) FB has "insights" which tell you "like" growth (decline) rate, click rate, view rate, repost rate, etc...you can download this all for free and create awesome crosstabs (if you know how to use Excel) with all sorts of data.

Additionally, HootSuite has SOME tools for free (such as click rate) and a sliding scale for other analytics.

Answer (score 0):

you should check out what we are building over here,  maybe you find it helpful, it is a web-store for social tools with hundreds of them. We are soon out for beta, grab your preinvite. Hope it helps. Anctu.com